# Terminal not working. Prompt gone!

Tags: command-line

I've closed the terminal killing a process, after that when opening a new terminal the prompt wasn't there.

After searching online other questions, with CTRL-C y get the prompt back.
However, when opening a new terminal the prompt is gone again.

I've tried the following code:

```
^Cmartin@martin-N550JV:~$ 
martin@martin-N550JV:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17626 pts/0    00:00:02 bash
20957 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
martin@martin-N550JV:~$ sudo kill 20957
[sudo] password for martin: 
martin@martin-N550JV:~$ sudo kill 17626
martin@martin-N550JV:~$
```

Taken from this [site](http://linuxservertutorials.blogspot.com.ar/2008/11/ubuntu-terminal-not-responding-tips.html)

I've also uninstalled and then re-installed the terminal, with no success.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Does the prompt disappear again if you type `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I've typed it, but I don't see a result.

Comment: @MartínBel plz tell me if you run `source ~/.bashrc` your prompt is going away or not? it will not solve your issue it is just a troubleshooting step.

Comment: @souravc The prompt goes away.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Have you tried `xterm` or `xfce4-terminal`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you open a terminal you get a non-login, interactive shell. If you are using `bash` the system-wide per-interactive-shell startup file is `/etc/bash.bashrc` and user-level per-interactive-shell startup file is `~/.bashrc`.

The problem you are facing may be due to presence of any bad instruction(s) in any of these two files.

**From OP's [reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427280/terminal-not-working-prompt-gone?noredirect=1#comment555462_427280):**

> sourcing `~/.bashrc` initiate the problem. That means there is problem with `~/.bashrc`

**Possible reasons of disappearing bash prompt:**

There might be recursive sourcing that can create an infinite loop type situation. For example if there are lines present in your `~/.bashrc` like,

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
   . ~/.profile
fi
```

It will source `~/.profile`. But keep in mind that `~/.profile` always sources `~/.bashrc` (it is correct way). Hence you are in an infinite loop. Do not source `~/.profile` from `~/.bashrc`

Under such situation you can not get the prompt unless you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

**Troubleshooting**

You can put a line in your `~/.bashrc`

```
set -x
```

Then you could see that the file descriptor is stopping when you open a terminal.

**How to recover**

Take backup of `~/.bashrc` and get a new one from `/etc/skel`. Use in terminal,

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/bashrc.bkp
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

It will replace your `~/.bashrc` with a new one.

Either the problem is like as I expected (described above) or something else should be solved after replacing `~/.bashrc` as it is solely related to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Plz let know if your problem still persists.

Comment: This worked just fine! Thanks for the help! I'll give you the points when the site allows me, in 8 hours.

Comment: `set -x` was the ticket to figuring out what command failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Running this command has solved this problem for me:

```
reset
```

Answer (score 2):

Check in `~/.bashrc` for anything that could block the execution.

Me was:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the shell prompt has been accidentally customized to be blank.

In a terminal window, do:

```
sudo cp /etc/bashrc /etc/bashrc.sav
sudo nano /etc/bashrc
```

Then change `PS1` to become:

```
PS1="[\u@\h:\w ] $ "
```

Save,  and exit.

The folowing command will show the `bashrc` files - what do you have?

```
ls -al /etc/ba*
```

Comment: This is what I get:`^Cmartin@martin-N550JV:~$ 
martin@martin-N550JV:~$ sudo cp /etc/bashrc /etc/bashrc.sav
[sudo] password for martin: 
cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/bashrc’: No such file or directory
`

Comment: See last two lines above.

Comment: First two lines`martin@martin-N550JV:~$ ls -al /etc/ba*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2177 mar 30  2013 /etc/bash.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   45 jun 17  2012 /etc/bash_completion
`

Comment: It seems the folder `bashrc` isn't there. `martin@martin-N550JV:/$ cd /etc
martin@martin-N550JV:/etc$ cd bashrc
bash: cd: bashrc: No such file or directory
martin@martin-N550JV:/etc$ `

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue of non-running, locked `lxterminal` and a mere `$` for the `xterm` prompt.

I found on my old N600C running Lubuntu 14.04 updated to 16.04, that `echo $0` told me I was running `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

After that it was just an issue of changing the default shell to `/bin/bash` in the way that I saw fit for my installation.
There are several ways to do that; they're outside the scope of the OP problem, though.

When I changed back to `/bin/bash`, it fixed `xterm` as well as `lxterminal`, now both show user, host, and `pwd`.